# Faster prime counting in python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, math, memoization

I can't count prime all prime number <= n. My code broken(Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)) on n⩽10**10.
Can anyone help me solve the problem in python?

````
import numpy as np
def count_primes_less_than(n):
    n +=1
    assert n >= 6
    sieve = np.ones(n // 3 + (n % 6 == 2), dtype=bool)
    sieve[0] = False
    for i in range(int(n ** 0.5) // 3 + 1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k = 3 * i + 1 | 1
            sieve[((k * k) // 3)::2 * k] = False
            sieve[(k * k + 4 * k - 2 * k * (i & 1)) // 3::2 * k] = False
    return len(np.r_[((3 * np.nonzero(sieve)[0] + 1) | 1)]) + 2```
````

Comment: Possibly faster to just count them as you generate them instead of counting the set bits in the sieve.

Comment: tbh you might need a better algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Lehmer_algorithm

Comment: try switching to `numba`

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error You help me solve problem. Thank you so much